# choose file from gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-gallery

In my application I want open only gallery application but when I did this

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

It's open dialog and ask me to choose from dialog, like shown in the picture.

I want show only gallery or open gallery directly. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE);
                dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the specific package to your intent. Try with:

```
// if this not work try with com.android.gallery3d
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent("com.android.gallery");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

But remember: If the app is not installed on the users phone this will not work so it is very recommendable to use the chooser.

Comment: Try waht works for you. It is the package from the app you want to start

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly for me.

1. `Intent i = new Intent(
                   Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           startActivityForResult(i,1);`
2. `Intent intent = new Intent();
                           intent.setType("image/*");
                           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                           startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);`

If you want to show the Gallery directly you can use

```
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: This definitely wouldn't work if you have multiple apps installed handling the same intent filter.

Comment: @humblerookie comments absolutely true

Comment: @pmb: while Cilenco's answer solves your purpose , to use an implicit intent with the class of the gallery app some devices may not have the same/ may have custom app to display gallery

Comment: @hublerookie @ wouldn't work if you have multiple apps installed handling the same intent filter :- that's how android works.